# Texfield contain integer, String or double value in java

Tags: java, swing, textfield

How to check the datatype of entered value in TextField? I have found other questions related to this query at Stack Overflow, but those are related to other languages, as: C#, Swift etc.

I don't want to parse the value of String to integer, or vise versa. I want to identify the Datatype of the value which is contained by jTextField1.

Usually in java, **jTextField1.getText();** returns the String value in Java. 
What I want is:

- if jTextField1 contains **Hello World** then answer should be **String**
- if jTextField1 contains **123** then answer should be **integer**
- if jTextField1 contains **354.55** then answer should be **Double**

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The "datatype" is String and nothing but String. Period. You say that you "don't want to parse" but that is precisely what you need to do, whether you want to or not.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels totally agreed. But still just to provide the op with some help I have posted some solution.

Comment: Once you get into dates, then all the fun begins with different possible formats...

Answer (score 0):

General - the datatype of a field is always String....

`Integer.parse` or `Double.parse` would be the most useful tools here, but if you dont want to use it, you can check each character individually if its a number `Character.isDigit`.

If any is not: String

If all are and no separator --> int

else --> double

but as said - I would use the existing api methods - because at the end, parsing is parsing